# Search on topic is not working as expected

Tags: discussion

I am searching questions on **apache camel** and I found 56 pages(each page contains 50 questions), but I am seeing couple of questions which are not tag with **apache camel** are also listed in the search result.

In the below screen shot question is tag with **java** and **message queue**, which is available as a search result of apache camel, but the question text contains apache camel in it.

[image]

Now, I am confused whether the search is based on **tagging** or it is based on question text also?

Comment: Use `[apache-camel]` in your search.

Comment: strange... I thought if I pass apache camel in the search is equivalent to [apache-camel], so what search it will do when I pass apache camel?

Comment: It will only automatically convert the most popular tags, to avoid accidentally converting things that it shouldn't. Using the tag name in square brackets always does a tag search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search feature on Stack Overflow is based on both question/answer text and tags.  If you include the *exact* name of one of the most popular tags in your search, it will be converted to a tag search automatically.

You're searching for "apache camel" which searches for posts where the two words "apache" and "camel" appear. If you want to limit your search to just posts tagged [apache-camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-camel), you have to use the hyphenated name, enclosed in square brackets, like `[apache-camel]`.